# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: The multi part identifier can not be bound using Hibernate and SQLServer After a hibernate migration

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

I'm building a project using hibernate spring here is my HQL query

```
select distinct new ma.mamda.per.model.Souscription(souscription.id, souscription.numeroPolice, souscription.dateEffet,
 souscription.cotisationPeriodique.epargne.montant,souscription.produit.familleproduit.code, souscription.garntieOptionnelle,
 souscription.dureeContrat, souscription.etat,
 souscription.souscripteur.nom, souscription.souscripteur.prenom,souscription.partenaire.libelle,souscription.partenaire.id,
 souscription.produit.libelle,assure.numeroCompte, assure.nom, assure.prenom)
 from  ma.mamda.per.model.Souscription as  souscription 
 left outer join  souscription.souscripteur as souscripteur 
 left outer join  souscription.cotisationPeriodique as cotisationPeriodique 
 left outer join  souscription.cotisationPeriodique.epargne as epargne  
 left outer join  souscription.partenaire as partenaire  
 left outer join  souscription.produit as produit 
 left outer join  souscription.produit.familleproduit  as familleproduit  
 left outer join  souscription.assure as assure  
 where  souscription.etat != 11 and  souscription.etat != 13 and produit.id = 1
```

And I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
Query q = getCurrentSession.createQuery(requete.toString());
try {
    SscrollableResults scrollableResults = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);
    int totalElements = scalculateTotalElementsByList(query);
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    if (log.isErrorEnabled())
        log.error("Failed to create ScrollPage by getScrollPageInstanceWithTotalByQuery: " + e.getMessage());
    throw e;
}
```

The code fails in scrollableResults = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY); and throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Failed to create ScrollPage by getScrollPageInstanceWithTotalByQuery: The multi part identifier "subscript0_1_.partenaire_id" can not be bound
Root Cause : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The multi part identifier "subscript0_1_.partenaire_id" can not be bound
```

The query used to work just fine in hibernate 3 but after the migration to hibernate 4 it throw the previous exception.
Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually occurs due to if the colu can't be bound that means there's something wrong with it - either you've got a simple typo, or a confusion between table and column. It can also be caused by using reserved words in your table or field names and not surrounding them with [].

Comment: But the query used to work just fine when i was using hibernate 3.Just after the upgrade to hibernate 4 that i faced this exception